# Sqlite3 is not inserting multiple rows in order

Tags: node.js, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working with node js application and database is sqlite3 (2.15.8). I am using [sqlite3 module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) . In this I have to insert rows in order.
I have table `tests` in which rows should be inserted as the same order in which they coming in loop.

My code is as follows:

**To create Table:**

```
GLOBAL.db1 = new sqlite3.Database(APPDATA+'/xyz/mydb.db');
var check;
db1.serialize(function() {

db1.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tests (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , parent_name varchar(255), test_name varchar(255), test_alias varchar(255), sequences varchar(55), duration varchar(55), prog_id int(11), org_id int(11), test_createdby int(11), test_created varchar(20), test_modified varchar(11), test_status int(11))");
});
```

**To Insert into Tables**

```
try{
                
  db1.run("INSERT INTO programs (`prog_name`, `prog_exercises`, `prog_orgid`, `prog_createdby`, `prog_created`, `prog_modified`, `prog_status`)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",program_name, JSON.stringify(step2PostedData), org_id, createdby, timestamp, timestamp, 0,function(err){
 // as it is single record insertion so inserting good obviously.
                    
if(err){
 throw err;
}else{
 for (i in step2PostedData.testsInfo) {
 
  var c = 0;
   
   for(j in step2PostedData.testsInfo[i]){
                        
   var obj = Object.keys(step2PostedData.testsInfo[i])[c];
   
   console.log(obj); // here I am getting correct order of test names in console
   
   db1.prepare("INSERT INTO `tests` ( `parent_name`,`test_name`, `test_alias`, `sequences`, `duration`, `prog_id`, `org_id`, `test_createdby`, `test_created`, `test_modified`, `test_status`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)").run('', obj, step2PostedData.testsInfo[i][j].alias, step2PostedData.testsInfo[i][j].sequences, step2PostedData.testsInfo[i][j].duration, this.lastID, org_id, createdby, timestamp, timestamp, 0);

     // Insertion is going in loop but order of insertion of rows is not same as per required                       
                            
     c++;
     }
    }
   }
  });
 }catch(ex){
    throw ex;
 }
```

But, when I am getting result in table then **order of rows inserted in `tests` table are not same as the same order in which I am sending into loop.** Can anyone please suggest me what should be changed there?

Thank you!

Comment: With most RDBMS, you can not expect _any_ specific order, unless you explicitly request one using ORDER BY. If without any ordering you get records back in the order you inserted them in – then that is pure coincidence, and nothing you should ever rely on.

Comment: But in console.log(obj); just before insertion, I am getting correct order in which I like to insert. Can we insert using Order by there ? please suggest , if yes then how ???

Comment: The order in which you insert the records does not matter. You need to specify an explicit order criterion when you _read_ the records from the database.

Comment: Order is dynamic always during insertion. Can you please suggest or answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There is no order in a relation

There is no order in a relation (i.e. in what people usually incorrectly call a "table") because relation is a set, not a list or array.

If people didn't incorrectly call relations "tables" then no one would expect an order from them. Unfortunately they do which leads to countless misconceptions that are so common that I wrote an article:

- [**What if I told you there are no tables in relational databases?**](https://medium.com/@pocztarski/what-if-i-told-you-there-are-no-tables-in-relational-databases-13d31a2f9677#.ghxe7le3e)

In short - don't expect any order from any set (this includes relations). If you want an order, use `sort` in SQL. If you want a specific order, add an integer value that you can sort to get the order that you need.

(Or don't use relational databases - there are other types of databases that support sorted structures like arrays. Relational databases don't support arrays - at least they shouldn't - and there is no implicit order in any relation.)

Comment: I have created a separate column for integer which contains the order number and during fetch data I have used order by in query. It works, Thank you!