# Wrong incrementation Nodejs & MySQL while looping an array for bulk insert

Tags: mysql, node.js, loops, increment

This is extremely weird. The code is kinda 500 rows of checks but it sums up to this

*I am using lodash, not that it matters*

```
var data = API.data
_.forEach(data, function (member, index, array) {
     var todoArray = []
     var todoNum = 0
     _.forEach(member.todos, function (spell, index, array) {
          .. bla bla bla
          todoArray.push([
              ...stuff,
              todoNum
          ])
          todoNum++
     })
     i.connection.query('INSERT INTO `static_todos` (`key`, `name`, `description`..) VALUES ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = VALUES(`name`)...;', [todoArray], function (err, result, fields) {
          // Throw stuff
     })
})
```

But when I go to the database, the rows are scrambled as well as the `todoNum`. I have no idea what is going on..

Edit; When I print the log after the 2nd `forEach` showing `todoArray` it show the right numbers and correct order.

Comment: What does your schema look like? MySQL is under no obligation to return things in any particular order unless you have an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Oh god .. I'm sorry I am an idiot, is there a button for this .. the numbers were fine after the bulk insert they were mess before that when I  put the queries inside the loop. Should I delete the question ?

Comment: Heh, no shame in solving the problem. You can always delete the question, or provide an answer that explains the solution if one's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having such kind of issue in my [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805789/sqlite3-inserting-multiple-rows-not-in-order) too.

**Don't expect any order from any set**. If you want a specific order, add an integer value that you can sort to get the order that you need.

So I have resolved that using extra column for manual order, check [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/e0209e)  in my case,

There is no order in a relation (i.e. in what people usually incorrectly call a "table") because relation is a set, not a list or array.

Comment: That's the same as what was on my screen after the bulk insert and I didn't even think to order it by num (it was sorted by the first column, which was a string primary key) I just thought it is still wrong .. I really need a rubber duck and stop bothering stackoverflow's finest with this..

Comment: when you will fetch then fetch order by column name ASC, it will provide you data in order